# Lines do not join where I want them to, ggplot, R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here are some codes which produce the following plot:

```
library(tidyverse)


p2_plt_data <-tibble(year = c(1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000), 
                     p2   = c(0, 0.00127, 0.0641, 0.85, 0, 0.765, 0.850, 0.85),
                     shape = rep(c("Slow", "Rapid"), each = 4),
                     vacc_cover = rep(c("Observed", "Interpolated","Interpolated", "Observed"), times = 2)  
                     ) 
  


ggplot(p2_plt_data, aes(x = year, y = p2, colour = vacc_cover)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = interaction(vacc_cover, shape)), size = 0.8) +
  geom_point(aes(group = interaction(vacc_cover, shape)), shape = 21, size = 2)
```

[image]

I wish to generate a plot where the blue lines are connected to the end of the orange lines which connect back to the blue lines.
Here, my objective is to differentiate between years that are interpolated and also display the differences in the shape interpolation types "Slow" and "Rapid".

I thought using interaction in my grouping argument might do it. But clearly not!

Can someone please help with this.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the eventual plot should look like and struggling a little bit - can you include a mockup of what you're looking for? I can't tell if it's supposed to be a Z shape where the bottom left corner of the blue line is connected to one of the orange lines or which orange line that would be.

Comment: and what color/type are those connecting lines meant to have?

Answer (score 0):

`geom_segment` to the rescue!

EDIT - using if_else to specifically exclude potential segments that would cross over both `shape` values:

```
ggplot(p2_plt_data, aes(x = year, y = p2, colour = vacc_cover)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend = if_else(lead(shape) == shape, lead(year), NA_real_),
                     yend = lead(p2)), size = 0.8) +
    geom_point(shape = 21, size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: This is nearly perfect @JonSpring! Is there any way of getting rid of the blue segment that diagonally connects the 1985 point to 2000? But thanks anyway!

Comment: Updated with an approach

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much. I only had to change to a NA_integer_ for it to work. I think that is perhaps because I have more than two shape values? Us of of a less stringent ifelse() instead of if_else() also seem to do the trick.